# Using Notepad++ Regex to remove anchors

Tags: notepad++, regex

I've tried looking at other answers for this and my brain just explodes when I try and read anything on Regex, I just cant comprehend it, no matter how many times I read it, or how slowly.

Im trying to remove this from a file using Notepad++:

`<a style="text-decoration:none" href="/SOME RANDOM WORD">.</a>`

But I am not sure what regex search string I need to use in Notepad++ to do this.   Where SOME RANDOM WORD is, this could literally be anything of any length, but the start and close of the tag / page its on is the same.

I just want to remove any instance of

`<a style="text-decoration:none" href="/SOME RANDOM WORD">.</a>`

and replace it with nothing.

Comment: I have tried <a style="text-decoration:none" href="/*">.</a> and that didnt work, I really dont understand regex at all, its like trying to teach a chip brain surgery, its just complete gibberish.

Comment: Please [edit] and provide some example lines showing before and after to clarify exactly what you want to do.

Comment: - [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
 - [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
 - [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)

Comment: I have read the above already but dont understand it, its like me giving you a book on brain surgery,the instructions are in the book, but the brain isnt complex enough to process the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Find what line, enter the following:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href=".+">\.</a>
```

Replace with: leave empty.

Then hit Replace all.

The key here is using `.+` which means, find one char of anything or more. This basically means, any url that has the text identical, but with any url, will be found and replaced. with nothing. It is possible to filter out the url or other things, but given that your post specified that you want to replace the entire string with nothing, this info was not provided to not confuse you any further.

Make sure, you select Regular Expression at the bottom, but I think you already thought of that.

Also, you have to escape special characters, such as the . If your links have actual text isntead of a ., you have to replace that `\.` with `.+` too.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help, that works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I am submitting another answer, not because I want to undermine the accepted answer, which is very good, but because your search expression was so nearly right.

The confusion is that in file masks `*` means an arbitrary string of any length (including zero), whereas in regular expressions it means any number of occurrences of the previous pattern. So what you asked for was a string containing any number of slashes (only) between the quotes in the `href=` clause.

What you needed was `href="/.*"` in your search expression, and this uses the other big difference between file masks, where `?` matches any single character, and regular expressions, where `.` is used, giving `.*` as any number of arbitrary characters.

The different use of `.` means that `>.</a>` at the end of your search expression means that any character between `>` and `</a>` will match: to match only a literal `.` you need to tell the search expression that you want to match it with a literal `.`, and you do this by preceding the `.` with the so-called *escape* character `\`. Thus `\.` matches a literal `.` and `\*` matches a literal `*`.

Your search string would have worked perfectly if regular expressions used the same matches as file masks, but unfortunately they don't, and what you need is:

```
<a style="text-decoration:none" href="/.*">\.</a>
```

As you see it is very little different from what you tried, with only two extra (but critical) characters, but I hope my explanation may give you the confidence to pursue them further: you are bound to need them again.

I cannot deny that they are forbidding, and I cannot recommend an easy way in, although you may find [this tester](https://regex101.com/) useful (although it does treat `/` as a special character which needs to be preceded by the escape character `\` - it does in some contexts, but not yours, so allow for this if you try it on your search expression).

Don't be put off because the expressions seem to be gobbledygook: I have been working with them for years and there still many which are beyond me, especially the check for binary numbers which are multiples of 3 in the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) - I have found explanations, but even with a degree in mathematics I cannot understand the expression in detail.

You understand file masks, and by using the simple modifications needed for regular expressions you have a starting point.

Comment: Good secondary answer. +1 from me. I'd like to add: I always test regex in notepad++ by putting my regex in the Find What field, then press find and see what it highlights.